# Memory leak with JAXB

Tags: java, dom, jaxb, out-of-memory

I am getting Out of Memory error:

```
Memory Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at org.apache.xerces.dom.CoreDocumentImpl.createElement(CoreDocumentImpl.java:564)
```

I have a standalone Java program which fetches data from DB and create an XML file using DOM. I get the above error if the data fetched is huge, **in my case it is > 1,000,000** records.

I have defined 2GB as heap size while calling the Java class from unix.

I tried it with JAXB, but still do not any significant improvement.

Any suggestions how to improve the code.

Comment: Why do you think there is a memory leak? If you use DOM, you're loading the whole document into memory at once. If the document is huge, your program will use a huge amount of memory and you might get an `OutOfMemoryError`. That error does not automatically mean that there is a memory leak.

Answer (score 6):

You should probably avoid loading the entire file into memory at once. To do this, switch from using DOM to another technology such as <strike>SAX or</strike> [StAX](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnbem.html). It is a streaming APIs and thus are more suited for handling huge amounts of XML data.

<sub>*Edit:* SAX doesn't support writing, therefore it's not applicable here.</sub>

Comment: @ Joachim - I tired with JAXB, but don't see any improvement. Can you provide some sample code how to use SAX. I am novice to this.

Comment: I didn't suggest JAXB, but if you really want to use it, then [this document](https://jaxb.dev.java.net/guide/Dealing_with_large_documents.html) might give useful hints.

Comment: The SAX tutorial you given is about parsing the existing XML.I am trying to create XML file with data fetched from DB.

Comment: I seem to have missed the "writing XML" part. In that case SAX doesn't help, however StAX **does** support writing XML in streaming mode, so that would be your best bet.

Comment: Yes, I am trying with StAX now. do you know how to validate the xml file created against an xsd file.

Comment: @Anurag: sure. And if you ask this in a separate question (or better yet: search for the answer on this site), then others can use the answer(s) as well!